# Using freetds to connect to Microsoft SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL server 2014 with Freetds but I'm stuck.

I get the following error

```
    locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
    locale charset is "UTF-8"
    using default charset "UTF-8"
    Default database being set to tempdb
    Error 100 (severity 11):
               unrecognized msgno
    Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 111, "Connection refused"
    There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I get this error when i,m running the command below.

**tsql -S SQLSERVER -U sa -P My_Password -D tempdb -p 1433**

I,m trying to connect to this server: WIN-SERVER-SQL.Assengraaf.nl

Running tsql -C Gives me again the TDS version 4.2

```
 Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 4.2
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: yes
```

These are my config files that I am using.

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
   #   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
   #
   # This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
   # name is found in the installation directory.
   #
   # For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
   # see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

   # Global settings are overridden by those in a database
   # server specific section
    [global]
            # TDS protocol version
            tds version = 8.0


            # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
            # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
            dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
            debug flags = 0xffff

            # Command and connection timeouts
            timeout = 10
            connect timeout = 10

            # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
            # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
            # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
            text size = 64512

 # A typical Sybase server
 [egServer50]
         host = symachine.domain.com
         port = 5000
         tds version = 5.0

 # A typical Microsoft server
 [SQLSERVER]
         host = WIN-SERVER-SQL.Assengraaf.nl
         port = 1433
         tds version = 7.2
         client charset = UTF-8
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
   [FreeTDS]
   Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
   #Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
   #Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
   Driver  = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodb.so
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
 [SQLSERVER]
 Driver = FreeTDS
 Server = WIN-SERVER-SQL.Assengraaf.nl
 Servername = SQLSERVER
 Port = 1433
 TDS_Version = 7.2
 Database = tempdb
 Driver = freetds
```

I followed the answer WEI_DBA gave me see link below.

[pyodbc not working on RedHat 5.4. Trying to connect to ms-sql database server using unixODBC and FreeTDS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918466/pyodbc-not-working-on-redhat-5-4-trying-to-connect-to-ms-sql-database-server-us?rq=1)

But that results in the error above.

I want to use Python in a later point so I can write data from my software to my MS SQL database but i,m trying to setup my test environment.

I think i,m doing something wrong regarding the driver.

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918466/pyodbc-not-working-on-redhat-5-4-trying-to-connect-to-ms-sql-database-server-us?rq=1

Comment: That looks like its trying to connect to a *Sybase* SQL Server (Adaptive Server), See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511369/adaptive-server-is-unavailable-or-does-not-exist-error-connecting-to-sql-serve

Comment: Why does your tsql-C output have a different version of TDS, 4.2 and your config files have 7.4 and 8.0?

Comment: Edited the files so that all config files used version 8 but after running tsql -C I still het the same output

Comment: Hmmm. Try reinstalling the latest version of the FreeTDS.

Comment: I.m gonna install it in my other test environment on my desktop I let you know how that works out.

Comment: so installed a new Linux server and a new MS SQL server 2014 i now get a new error ill edit my post so you guys can see the new error i am having trouble with.